# DMwR linux missing packages

Tags: linux, r

I have linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64-bit, kernel 3.13.0-37-generic and I have to install DMwR package into my R. When I am trying install this package, I have this error:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o KernSmooth.so blkest.o cp.o dgedi.o dgefa.o dgesl.o init.o linbin.o linbin2D.o locpoly.o rlbin.o sdiag.o sstdiag.o -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [KernSmooth.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘KernSmooth’
* removing ‘/home/benik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/KernSmooth’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘KernSmooth’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘KernSmooth’ is not available for package ‘gplots’
* removing ‘/home/benik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/gplots’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gplots’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gplots’ is not available for package ‘ROCR’
* removing ‘/home/benik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/ROCR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ROCR’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ROCR’ is not available for package ‘DMwR’
* removing ‘/home/benik/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/DMwR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘DMwR’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpozPYSg/downloaded_packages’
```

Google have absolutely no answer for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why Google when `ld` tells you which library to install ;-) To be able to link you often need the `-dev` version of the package:

```
apt-get install libblas3-dev
```

Comment: Actually I installed libblas3 and this not helped. But libblas-dev helped. So your answer was usesfull. Thank you.